# problems with .htaccess redirection and RewriteRule (with or without RewriteCond)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to set up the url **`http://subdomain.example.com/test`** and make it able to call the real file **`/my-test-script.php`**.

I can't understand why the following code works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?test\/?$
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

while this one does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\/?test\/?$ /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Is it mandatory the RewriteCond? If not, what do I miss?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
**`.htaccess`** and **`my-test-script.php`** are both in the root /.

**EDIT 2:**
Funny update: I see it works with

```
RewriteRule test /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

but not with

```
RewriteRule ^test$ /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

**EDIT 3:**
I created a script that shows the $_GET parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/?show\-parameters\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /show\-parameters.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

and when I call `http://subdomain.example.com/test` I see:

```
Array ( [path] => /var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain/test )
```

**EDIT 4:**
Here my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    RewriteEngine On

    ### HTTP: from www to non-www ###
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        RewriteBase /

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain

    RewriteEngine On

    ### HTTP: from www to non-www ###
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            RewriteBase /
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**[SOLVED] EDIT 5:**
I simply removed the `RewriteBase /` line from the .htaccess and the following rule now works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/?test\/?$ /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: no, it is not a directory and the .htaccess is in the root of the domain. In the same folder of `my-test-script.php`

Comment: Apache/2.4.7. The DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain/`

Comment: yes, they are both in `/var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain/`

Comment: Does `RewriteRule (^|/)test/?$ my-test-script.php [NC,L]` work?

Comment: Almost. It works only if I add a slash before the script: `**/**my-test-script.php`. Anyway see my new **EDIT 3**, I think I found the problem: the path contains all the folder chain. How to fix it?

Comment: I think there is some misconfiguration because `$1` must never have full path like shown above. Can you share `VirtualHost` config of your subdomain?

Comment: Added VirtualHost config in **EDIT 4**

Comment: `www.subdomain.example.coms` << Is that s an typo in your Virtual Host? Also, can you try to remove the `RewriteBase /` from your vhost?

Comment: Yes `RewriteBase /` should be removed and restart the apache

Comment: @KayVan: I have no typos in VirtualHost config, I wrongly added an extra s in copy/paste process. @anubhava: Removed `RewriteBase /` from VirtualHost with no luck. The path passed via $1 is still the whole path...

Answer (score 1):

Is your `my-test-script.php` located at the same level of your `.htaccess`? If so, just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/?$ my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: .htaccess and my-test-script.php are in the same folder (I will edit my question). Sadly your solutions does not work.

Comment: http://example.com/test (sadly I can't currently share a real public url but it has exactly the same structure - protocol, domain, path)

Comment: oh, yes, sorry: `http://subdomain.example.com/test`. Anyway, I tried with the main domain also and I got the same results

Comment: No. I also tried starting with `/client/project_name/domain/subdomain/` and removing one level at each attempt. The main DocumentRoot of Apache is `/var/www/html/`. The domain `example.com` is set up under `/var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/`. The subdomain.example.com points to `/var/www/html/client/project_name/domain/subdomain/`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/test/?$ /my-test-script.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Try that instead. That works for me on a test environment I have.

Comment: It does not work:

`Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.`